# Bracket Error when trying to make an if statement?

Tags: bukkit

I have been making a plugin for Minecraft, but that's not important in this post. My code seems to have enough brackets but only works if I remove the brackets, and then the code will always run which i do not want. Here is my code -

```
package me.impatheimpaler.soundpickup;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.Sound;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerPickupItemEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class SoundPickups extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{


public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}

public void onDisable() {

}

 @EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.LOWEST)
  public void MoneyPickUp(PlayerPickupItemEvent event)  {
  if {
      (event.getItem().getItemStack().getType() == Material.GOLD_INGOT);
      event.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "+" + ChatColor.GOLD +       event.getItem().getItemStack().getAmount() + ChatColor.GOLD + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "G");
      event.getPlayer().playSound(event.getPlayer().getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 1, 1);

 }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in

```
@EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.LOWEST)
public void MoneyPickUp(PlayerPickupItemEvent event)  {
if {
  (event.getItem().getItemStack().getType() == Material.GOLD_INGOT);
    event.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "+" + ChatColor.GOLD + event.getItem().getItemStack().getAmount() + ChatColor.GOLD + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "G");
    event.getPlayer().playSound(event.getPlayer().getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

You're opening a bracket right after an `if` statement, if you're going to use a bracket with an if should be like this:

```
if(conditional) {
//My code here
}
```

If you remove the brackets it works, but your code does not execute properly because you're putting a semicolon `;` right after the conditional

Change your code to this:

```
@EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.LOWEST)
public void MoneyPickUp(PlayerPickupItemEvent event) {
  if (event.getItem().getItemStack().getType() == Material.GOLD_INGOT) {
    event.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "+" + ChatColor.GOLD + event.getItem().getItemStack().getAmount() + ChatColor.GOLD + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "G");
    event.getPlayer().playSound(event.getPlayer().getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 1, 1);
  }
}
```